# FTP batch script is not exiting with error status

Tags: batch-file, ftp

There is a ftp command in my batch script :

FTP -n -s:D:\scripts\Test\get.ftp

Where get.ftp contains all ftp commands including "mget abc*".

Issue here is when file(s) of names starting with abc* is not available, mget is not failing. Also, if any other ftp command fails also, the script is not exiting with error status 1. i.e. "FTP -n -s:D:\scripts\Test\get.ftp" exiting without issues.

Not able to make the batch script fail when there is no file to pick up.

Need suggestion if someone has faced similar issue.

-Krishna

Answer (score 1):

The mget command works by obtaining a remote folder listing and parsing the list for the wildcard pattern that you provide. As long as the listing can be obtained successfully,
it is not considered an error if your pattern did not match any of the files on the list.

Your batch script can be setup to compare the local folder listing before and after invoking the ftp command to check if a file was downloaded. You can also use a scripted ftp solution like [kermit](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/) or [ftp script](http://www.sysax.com/ftpauto/) to be able to have more control on error reporting.